Why is the event listener not working properly?
I am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I tried to add an event listener so to check whenever the button is clicked and added a condition to check whose turn it is. When clicked it should display the button is clicked and print the text according to the condition whenever the button is clicked.


let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let turnO = true;
const winningPatterns = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
];

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("onclick", () => {
    console.log("box was clicked");
    if (turnO) { //checking whether it is the turn O's turn 
      box.innerText = "O";
      turnO = false;
    } else {
      box.innerText = "X"; //checking whether it is the turn of X's
      turnO = true;
    }
  });
});
/* CSS added by Editor for demo purpose */
.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  .box {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 2em;
  }
}
<main>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="game">
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
</main>



I want it to display whether the button is clicked and also whoever's turn it is but the buttons are not working .  I have connected my script file corectly with html. I want to know where I am making mistake.

You need to listen to the click event. There is no event with the name onclick.

@JSONDerulo you probably mean the right thing but phrased it wrongly. An onlick event does exist! Just not when appending it with addEventListener.

but why is it not working in Js, it works when i add onclick in the html . It displays that the button is clicked . But when i use it in Js it doesn't work.  Did i do something wrong while access the box in JS.

"click" is the event name you need to use. also you can avoid using 9 event listeners. You can just use one.


const boxesContainer = document.querySelector(".game");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset-btn");
let turnO = true;
const winningPatterns = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
];

function onBoxHandler(event) {
    const box = event.target;
    if (!(box instanceof HTMLButtonElement)) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("box was clicked");
    if (turnO) { //checking whether it is the turn O's turn 
      box.innerText = "O";
      turnO = false;
    } else {
      box.innerText = "X"; //checking whether it is the turn of X's
      turnO = true;
    }
  }


boxesContainer.addEventListener("click", onBoxHandler);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (const box of boxesContainer.querySelectorAll(".box")) {
     box.innerText = "";
  }
})
/* CSS added by Editor for demo purpose */
.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  .box {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 2em;
  }
}
<main>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="game">
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
</main>




You mistaken the onclick even with the click event. If you use onclick you have to use element.onclick = function() { ... } which attaches an event to an element and overwrites all previous events.
If you append events with addEventListener you have to listen to click events such as element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }).
However, the smarter move would be to use an event delegation on the container and check if the clicked element is a button and if the button is empty:


const PLAYERS = ['X', 'O'];
let turn = 0;
const winningPatterns = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
];

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.textContent === '') {
    e.target.textContent = PLAYERS[turn];
    turn = (turn + 1) % PLAYERS.length;
  }
})
/* CSS added by Editor for demo purpose */
.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  .box {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 2em;
  }
}
<main>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="game">
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
</main>



Side note: Your code could be greatly improved. The game data should be stored in JS and depending on that update the HTML. The game data should actually not be stored in HTML and let JS read that out. If you're interested there was a review of one of my Tic-Tac-Toe attempts that explains that pretty well:
Tic-Tac-Toe on Code Review

ok Thanks a lot! I get it now

You want to bind to the "click" event, not "onclick".
Event delegation is useful when you have a large amount of children listeners. In this case, we know we will always have 9 so maybe delegation isn't worth the extra trouble.
addEventListener is overloaded to accept options, allowing us to configure the listener further -
addEventListener(type, listener)
addEventListener(type, listener, options)
addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)

The options parameter has the following type -
{
   capture?: boolean
   once?: boolean
   passive?: boolean
   signal?: AbortSignal
}

Consider using { once: true } to ensure a listener will only trigger once per button click -


let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box")
let turnO = true

for (const box of boxes) {
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    box.innerText = turnO ? "O" : "X"
    turnO = !turnO
  }, { once: true })
}
.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  .box {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 2em;
  }
}
<main>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="game">
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
      <button class="box"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



